# JBoss 4.2.3 startup/deployment with EJB

Tags: jboss

When I start the *JBoss 4.2.3* server at that time it is not getting started properly. As well as when I try to deploy any jar file it is not able to deploy. Following is the console log:

```
14:42:14,591 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)
14:42:14,591 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: C:\Users\nishat.l\Desktop\JBoss_4_2_3
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Home URL:file:/C:/Users/nishat.l/Desktop/JBoss_4_2_3/
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Server Name: all
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: C:\Users\nishat.l\Desktop\JBoss_4_2_3\server\all
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/C:/Users/nishat.l/Desktop/JBoss_4_2_3/server/all/
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: C:\Users\nishat.l\Desktop\JBoss_4_2_3\server\all\log
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: C:\Users\nishat.l\Desktop\JBoss_4_2_3\server\all\tmp
14:42:14,601 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
14:42:14,873 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.8.0_20,Oracle Corporation
14:42:14,873 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.20-b23,Oracle Corporation
14:42:14,873 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
14:42:15,267 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
14:42:17,328 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://localhost:8083/
14:42:17,338 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
14:42:17,719 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
14:42:17,719 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
14:42:17,969 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
14:42:18,049 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
14:42:18,049 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
14:42:19,729 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
14:42:22,060 WARN  [UDP] failed to join /224.0.0.75:7500 on net5: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: no Inet4Address associated with interface
14:42:22,061 INFO  [STDOUT] 
GMS: address is 127.0.0.1:53409
14:42:24,091 INFO  [TreeCache] viewAccepted(): [127.0.0.1:53409|0] [127.0.0.1:53409]
14:42:24,095 INFO  [TreeCache] TreeCache local address is 127.0.0.1:53409
14:42:24,095 INFO  [TreeCache] State could not be retrieved (we are the first member in group)
14:42:24,095 INFO  [TreeCache] parseConfig(): PojoCacheConfig is empty
14:42:25,745 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
14:42:25,745 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA (build=200803312044)
14:42:26,370 INFO  [SnmpAgentService] SNMP agent going active
14:42:26,706 INFO  [DefaultPartition] Initializing
14:42:27,049 WARN  [UDP] failed to join /224.0.0.75:7500 on net5: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: no Inet4Address associated with interface
```

Comment: I am wondering how are you using JBoss 4.x with Java 8? Jboss 4.x runs with Java 5. The other thing is try to check that you (your JRE) are/is not using IPv6, use IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a simple mistake and logs saying that here:

WARN  [UDP] failed to join /224.0.0.75:7500 on net5: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: no Inet4Address associated with interface

It means you have configured an IP in your configuration file for example standalone.xml which is invalid(224.0.0.75). Try to see your ip using command:

```
ifconfig (For Linux)
ipconfig (For Windows)
```

and grab your ip then simply change ip of your configuration file.

Comment: There is no standalone.xml file in jboss 4.2

Comment: Then where you configured your ip? 224.0.0.75? This is not a valid IP of that machine

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 i've had the same issue with jboss-4.2.2.GA.

I've managed to make it work by starting the server with the -b switch:

```
run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```